# C++: using mem fun for own structure

Tags: c++, stl

The example for this function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun/
does say that std::string::length can be passed as last parameter of std;:transform. Due to manual, std::string::length is not static (correct me if I'm wrong)

I assumed that I can create own structure/class, and pass it's member as last param of std::transform, e.g.:

```
struct ss
{
  int ssFun(int n)
  {
    return 2*n;
  } 
};
```

So I could do following:

```
int tab[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> inVect( tab, tab+5 );
std::vector<int> outVect;
ss myStruct;

outVect.resize(5);
std::mem_fun( inVect.begin(), inVect.end(), outVect.begin(), mem_fun( &ss::ssFun ) );
```

Neither this:

```
std::mem_fun( inVect.begin(), inVect.end(), outVect.begin(), mem_fun( myStruct.ssFun ) );
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Why?

Comment: Did you mean `std::transform` instead of `std::mem_fun`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `std::mem_fun` returns a function object that must be called with a parameter that is the object off of which to invoke the member function. For example:

```
auto fun = std::mem_fun(&S::sayHello);

S s;
fun(s); // "Hello"
```

Inside `std::transform`, the functor object is called with the elements of the vector from `[inVect.begin(), inVect.end())`, which are integers (not meant to be the objects to call the member functions on). If the range of those elements were elements of type `ss` it would have worked (kind of), but since the function is being called with `int`s, it won't work. To circumvent this, we have to `std::bind` the member function to the instance variable before starting `std::transform`.

```
std::transform(inVect.begin(), inVect.end(),
               outVect.begin(), std::bind(&ss::ssFun, myStruct));
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```